# Creating a series expansion from two functions multiplied together

Tags: sequences-and-series

First I have this function:

$$g_0(1,\eta)=\frac{\frac{3\eta}{\eta_c-\eta}+\sum_{k=1}^4kA_k\left(\frac{\eta}{\eta_c}\right)^k}{4\eta}$$

I need to multiply this function by another function:

Full polynomial function:

$$C00*r^0*rpf^0 + C10*r^1*rpf^0 + C20*r^2*rpf^0 + C30*r^3*rpf^0 + C40*r^4*rpf^0 + C50*r^5*rpf^0 + C60*r^6*rpf^0 + C01*r^0*rpf^1 + C11*r^1*rpf^1 + C21*r^2*rpf^1 + C31*r^3*rpf^1 + C41*r^4*rpf^1+ C51*r^5*rpf^1 + C61*r^6*rpf^1 + C02*r^0*rpf^2 + C12*r^1*rpf^2 
 + C22*r^2*rpf^2 + C32*r^3*rpf^2 + C42*r^4*rpf^2 + C52*r^5*rpf^2 + C62*r^6*rpf^2 + C03*r^0*rpf^3 + C13*r^1*rpf^3 + C23*r^2*rpf^3 + C33*r^3*rpf^3 + C43*r^4*rpf^3 + C53*r^5*rpf^3 + C63*r^6*rpf^3+ C04*r^0*rpf^4 + C14*r^1*rpf^4 + C24*r^2*rpf^4 + C34*r^3*rpf^4 + C44*r^4*rpf^4 + C54*r^5*rpf^4 + C64*r^6*rpf^4 + C05*r^0*rpf^5 + C15*r^1*rpf^5 + C25*r^2*rpf^5 + C35*r^3*rpf^5 + C45*r^4*rpf^5
 + C55*r^5*rpf^5 + C65*r^6*rpf^5 + C06*r^0*rpf^6 + C16*r^1*rpf^6 +
 + C26*r^2*rpf^6 + C36*r^3*rpf^6 + C46*r^4*rpf^6 + C56*r^5*rpf^6 + 
 + C66*r^6*rpf^6;$$

Note that rpf is just $\eta/\eta_c$

Then I need to accumulate all terms in a series expansion about $\frac{\eta}{\eta_c}=0$. I need to collect the coefficients in front of each order polynomial. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What is $r$? Just a number? Are there any powers to $\frac{\eta}{\eta_c}$? What you need to do is write the expansion of both functions, say $\sum_i a_ix^i$ and $\sum_i b_ix^i$, then the product can be written as $\sum_{i+j} a_ib_j x^{i+j}$

Comment: There are other terms with powers of $\eta/\eta_c$ but there's are not important for what I'm trying to do. I'm not sure how to get the total series expansion. I need to get the coefficients in front of each term. r is a variable, just like $\eta/\eta_c$ is a variable It's a function of two variables.

Comment: Where is this problem coming from? I think you might be complicating it too much.

Comment: What is the coefficient in front of each term?

Comment: If you start the sum from $0$ in each individual series, then you have $(a_0 b_0)+(a_1 b_0+a_0b_1)x+(a_2b_0+a_1b_1+a_0b_2)x^2+(a_3b_0+a_2b_1+a_1b_2+a_0b_3)x^3+...$

Comment: I added the full polynomial. After the 2 functions are multiplied together, all I care about are the $\left(\eta/\eta_c\right)^1$ terms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91625/discussion-between-andrei-and-jackson-hart).

Comment: Just an earnest suggestion: it hinders readability to use asterisk for multiplication. Far better to write “$ab$” than “$a*b$”. If “rpf ” is a word or stands for an expression, you should either use a single letter or (worse) make it roman rather than italic.

Answer (score 1):

Since $rpf=\frac{\eta}{\eta_C}$ the polynomial can be written as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^6\sum_{l=0}^6C_{j,l}r^j\left(\frac{\eta}{\eta_C}\right)^l\tag{1}
\end{align*}
The function $g_0\left(1,\eta\right)$ can be written assuming $\left|\frac{\eta}{\eta_C}\right|<1$ as
\begin{align*}
g_0\left(1,\eta\right)&=\frac{\frac{3\eta}{\eta_c-\eta}+\sum_{k=1}^4kA_k\left(\frac{\eta}{\eta_c}\right)^k}{4\eta}\\
&=\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{\eta_C-\eta}+\frac{1}{4\eta_C}\sum_{k=1}^4kA_k\left(\frac{\eta}{\eta_C}\right)^{k-1}\\
&=\frac{3}{4\eta_C}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{\eta}{\eta_C}\right)^k+\frac{1}{4\eta_C}\sum_{k=1}^4kA_k\left(\frac{\eta}{\eta_C}\right)^{k-1}\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}

According to a comment from OP the focus is the linear term of the product of the polynomial with $g_0$. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$.

> Let $z=\frac{\eta}{\eta_C}$. We obtain from (1) and (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[z^1]}&\color{blue}{\left(\frac{3}{4\eta_C}\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k+\frac{1}{4\eta_C}\sum_{k=0}^3(k+1)A_{k+1}z^{k}\right)
> \sum_{j=0}^6\sum_{l=0}^6C_{j,l}r^jz^l}\\
> &=\frac{3}{4\eta_C}\sum_{k=0}^1 [z^{1-k}]\sum_{j=0}^6\sum_{l=0}^6C_{j,l}r^jz^l
> +\frac{1}{4\eta_C}\sum_{k=0}^1[z^{1-k}](k+1)A_{k+1}
> \sum_{j=0}^6\sum_{l=0}^6C_{j,l}r^jz^l\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{3}{4\eta_C}\left([z^0]+[z^1]\right)\sum_{j=0}^6\sum_{l=0}^6C_{j,l}r^jz^l
> +\frac{1}{4\eta_C}\left(2A_2[z^0]+A_1[z^1]\right)
> \sum_{j=0}^6\sum_{l=0}^6C_{j,l}r^jz^l\\
> &=\frac{3}{4\eta_C}\sum_{j=0}^6\left(C_{j,0}+C_{j,1}\right)r^j
> +\frac{1}{4\eta_C}\sum_{j=0}^6\left(2A_2C_{j,0}+A_1C_{j,1}\right)r^j\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{4\eta_C}\sum_{j=0}^6\left((3+2A_2)C_{j,0}+(3+A_1)C_{j,1}\right)r^j}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$. We restrict the upper index of the sums with $1$ since other terms do not contribute to $z^1$.
- In (4) we select the coefficients accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you care only about the $(\eta/\eta_c)^1$ terms, you can safely ignore higher order terms in both expansions. From your previous question, you can write $g_0=a+b*rpf$. From your polynomial just keep terms of $rpf^0$ and $rpf^1$, so you are left with $c+d*rpf$. Here $c=C00*r^0 + C10*r^1 + C20*r^2 + C30*r^3 + C40*r^4 + C50*r^5 + C60*r^6$ and $d=C01*r^0+ C11*r^1 + C21*r^2 + C31*r^3 + C41*r^4+ C51*r^5 + C61*r^6$. With these, the product becomes $$ac+(ad+bc)*rpf+bd*rpf^2$$
And you can ignore the last term, since it's already higher power in $rpf$.